# Creating a df with index = years and columns = mean length of an event occurring in a year, from previous df columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the df_winter as viewed below, and would like to create a new df that displays the year, and the average length of storms occuring in a 1 year, so I can visualize the change in length of storms over time.

I thought I could use groupby like this:

```
df_winter_length= df_winter.groupby(['Start_year', 'Disaster_Length']).mean()
```

However, I receive the error : DataError: No Numeric types to aggregate

so I printed:

print(df_winter.Disaster_Length.dtype)
return: int64

Which as an int64, I thought could be calculated. What am I missing? Thanks!

Entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 


df_time = pd.read_pickle('df_time.pkl')


df_winter = df_time[(df_time['Disaster_Type'] == 'Winter') | (df_time['Disaster_Type'] == 'Snow') | (df_time['Disaster_Type'] == 'Ice')]

df_winter.drop(columns=['Start_Date_A', 'End_Date_A'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_winter.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

df_winter = df_winter.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)

#Change in Average Length of Winter Weather Events from 1965 - 2017

df_winter_length= df_winter.groupby(['Start_year', 'Disaster_Length']).mean()
```

df_winter :

```
                                               County Disaster_Type  Disaster_Length  Start_year
2400                                     Perry County          Snow                7        1996
2401                                      Pike County          Snow                7        1996
2402                                    Powell County          Snow                7        1996
2403                                   Pulaski County          Snow                7        1996
2404                                 Robertson County          Snow                7        1996
2405                                Rockcastle County          Snow                7        1996
2406                                     Rowan County          Snow                7        1996
2407                                   Russell County          Snow                7        1996
2408                                     Scott County          Snow                7        1996
2409                                    Shelby County          Snow                7        1996
2410                                   Simpson County          Snow                7        1996
2411                                   Spencer County          Snow                7        1996
2412                                    Taylor County          Snow                7        1996
2413                                      Todd County          Snow                7        1996
2414                                     Trigg County          Snow                7        1996
2415                                   Trimble County          Snow                7        1996
2416                                     Union County          Snow                7        1996
2417                                    Warren County          Snow                7        1996
2418                                Washington County          Snow                7        1996
2419                                     Wayne County          Snow                7        1996
2420                                   Webster County          Snow                7        1996
2421                                   Whitley County          Snow                7        1996
2422                                     Wolfe County          Snow                7        1996
2423                                  Woodford County          Snow                7        1996
2424                                Barnstable County          Snow                6        1996
2425                                 Berkshire County          Snow                6        1996
2426  Bristol County(in PMSA 1120,1200,2480,5400,6060          Snow                6        1996
2427                                     Dukes County          Snow                6        1996
2428              Essex County(in PMSA 1120,4160,7090          Snow                6        1996
2429                                  Franklin County          Snow                6        1996
2430                                   Hampden County          Snow                6        1996
2431                                 Hampshire County          Snow                6        1996
2432          Middlesex County(in PMSA 1120,2600,4560          Snow                6        1996
2433                                 Nantucket County          Snow                6        1996
2434            Norfolk County(in PMSA 1120,1200,6060          Snow                6        1996
2435           Plymouth County(in PMSA 1120,1200,5400          Snow                6        1996
2436                                   Suffolk County          Snow                6        1996
2437          Worcester County in PMSA 1120,2600,9240          Snow                6        1996
2438                                   Bristol County          Snow                6        1996
2439                                      Kent County          Snow                6        1996
2440                 Newport County(in PMSA 2480,6480          Snow                6        1996
2441              Providence County(in PMSA 6060,6480          Snow                6        1996
2442              Washington County(in PMSA 5520,6480          Snow                6        1996
2443     Fairfield County(in PMSA 1160,1930,5760,8040          Snow                6        1996
2444           Hartford County(in PMSA 1170,3280,5440          Snow                6        1996
2445    Litchfield County(in PMSA 1170,1930,3280,8880          Snow                6        1996
2446          Middlesex County(in PMSA 3280,5020,5480          Snow                6        1996
2447          New Haven County(in PMSA 1160,5480,8880          Snow                6        1996
2448              New London County(in PMSA 3280,5520          Snow                6        1996
2449                                   Tolland County          Snow                6        1996
2450                                   Windham County          Snow                6        1996
2451                                 Alexander County          Snow                7        1996
2452                                     Burke County          Snow                7        1996
2453                                  Caldwell County          Snow                7        1996
2454                                   Caswell County          Snow                7        1996
2455                                   Catawba County          Snow                7        1996
2456                                  Cherokee County          Snow                7        1996
2457                                 Cleveland County          Snow                7        1996
2458                                  Davidson County          Snow                7        1996
2459                                     Davie County          Snow                7        1996
2460                                   Forsyth County          Snow                7        1996
2461                                    Gaston County          Snow                7        1996
2462                                     Gates County          Snow                7        1996
2463                                  Guilford County          Snow                7        1996
2464                                   Halifax County          Snow                7        1996
2465                                   Haywood County          Snow                7        1996
2466                                 Henderson County          Snow                7        1996
2467                                  Hertford County          Snow                7        1996
2468                                   Iredell County          Snow                7        1996
2469                                   Lincoln County          Snow                7        1996
2470                                  McDowell County          Snow                7        1996
2471                                   Madison County          Snow                7        1996
2472                                Montgomery County          Snow                7        1996
2473                               Northampton County          Snow                7        1996
2474                                      Polk County          Snow                7        1996
2475                                  Randolph County          Snow                7        1996
2476                                Rockingham County          Snow                7        1996
2477                                Rutherford County          Snow                7        1996
2478                                    Stokes County          Snow                7        1996
2479                                     Surry County          Snow                7        1996
2480                                    Warren County          Snow                7        1996
2481                                   Watauga County          Snow                7        1996
2482                                    Wilkes County          Snow                7        1996
2483                                    Yadkin County          Snow                7        1996
2484                                    Yancey County          Snow                7        1996
2485                                 Klickitat County           Ice               15        1996
2486                              Pend Oreille County           Ice               15        1996
2487                                   Spokane County           Ice               15        1996
2488                                      Cass County          Snow                2        1997
2489                                    Clarke County          Snow                2        1997
2490                                      Iowa County          Snow                2        1997
2491                                    Jasper County          Snow                2        1997
2492                                   Madison County          Snow                2        1997
2493                                   Mahaska County          Snow                2        1997
2494                                    Marion County          Snow                2        1997
2495                                     Mills County          Snow                2        1997
2496                                      Polk County          Snow                2        1997
2497                             Pottawattamie County          Snow                2        1997
2498                                 Poweshiek County          Snow                2        1997
2499                                     Union County          Snow                2        1997
2500                                    Warren County          Snow                2        1997
2501                                   Clinton County          Snow               12        1998
2502                                     Essex County          Snow               12        1998
2503                                  Franklin County          Snow               12        1998
2504                                   Genesee County          Snow               12        1998
2505                                 Jefferson County          Snow               12        1998
2506                                     Lewis County          Snow               12        1998
2507                                    Monroe County          Snow               12        1998
2508                                   Niagara County          Snow               12        1998
2509                              St. Lawrence County          Snow               12        1998
2510                                  Saratoga County          Snow               12        1998
2511                                     Adams County          Snow               14        1999
2512                                     Brown County          Snow               14        1999
2513                                    Bureau County          Snow               14        1999
2514                                   Calhoun County          Snow               14        1999
2515                                      Cass County          Snow               14        1999
2516                                 Champaign County          Snow               14        1999
2517                                 Christian County          Snow               14        1999
2518                                      Cook County          Snow               14        1999
2519                                   De Witt County          Snow               14        1999
2520                                   Douglas County          Snow               14        1999
2521                                    DuPage County          Snow               14        1999
2522                                      Ford County          Snow               14        1999
2523                                    Fulton County          Snow               14        1999
2524                                    Greene County          Snow               14        1999
2525                                    Grundy County          Snow               14        1999
2526                                   Hancock County          Snow               14        1999
2527                                 Henderson County          Snow               14        1999
2528                                     Henry County          Snow               14        1999
2529                                  Iroquois County          Snow               14        1999
2530                                      Kane County          Snow               14        1999
2531                                  Kankakee County          Snow               14        1999
2532                                   Kendall County          Snow               14        1999
2533                                      Knox County          Snow               14        1999
2534                                      Lake County          Snow               14        1999
2535                                  La Salle County          Snow               14        1999
2536                                Livingston County          Snow               14        1999
2537                                     Logan County          Snow               14        1999
2538                                 McDonough County          Snow               14        1999
2539                                   McHenry County          Snow               14        1999
2540                                    McLean County          Snow               14        1999
2541                                     Macon County          Snow               14        1999
2542                                  Marshall County          Snow               14        1999
2543                                     Mason County          Snow               14        1999
2544                                    Menard County          Snow               14        1999
2545                                    Mercer County          Snow               14        1999
2546                                    Morgan County          Snow               14        1999
2547                                  Moultrie County          Snow               14        1999
2548                                    Peoria County          Snow               14        1999
2549                                     Piatt County          Snow               14        1999
2550                                      Pike County          Snow               14        1999
2551                                    Putnam County          Snow               14        1999
2552                                  Sangamon County          Snow               14        1999
2553                                  Schuyler County          Snow               14        1999
2554                                     Scott County          Snow               14        1999
2555                                    Shelby County          Snow               14        1999
2556                                     Stark County          Snow               14        1999
2557                                  Tazewell County          Snow               14        1999
2558                                 Vermilion County          Snow               14        1999
2559                                    Warren County          Snow               14        1999
2560                                      Will County          Snow               14        1999
2561                                 Winnebago County          Snow               14        1999
2562                                  Woodford County          Snow               14        1999
2563                               Cattaraugus County          Snow               14        1999
2564                                Chautauqua County          Snow               14        1999
2565                                      Erie County          Snow               14        1999
2566                                   Genesee County          Snow               14        1999
2567                                 Jefferson County          Snow               14        1999
2568                                     Lewis County          Snow               14        1999
2569                                   Niagara County          Snow               14        1999
2570                                   Orleans County          Snow               14        1999
2571                              St. Lawrence County          Snow               14        1999
2572                                   Wyoming County          Snow               14        1999
2573                                     Adams County          Snow               14        1999
2574                                     Allen County          Snow               14        1999
2575                                    Benton County          Snow               14        1999
2576                                 Blackford County          Snow               14        1999
2577                                     Boone County          Snow               14        1999
2578                                   Carroll County          Snow               14        1999
2579                                      Cass County          Snow               14        1999
2580                                      Clay County          Snow               14        1999
2581                                   Clinton County          Snow               14        1999
2582                                    DeKalb County          Snow               14        1999
2583                                  Delaware County          Snow               14        1999
2584                                   Elkhart County          Snow               14        1999
2585                                   Fayette County          Snow               14        1999
2586                                  Fountain County          Snow               14        1999
2587                                    Fulton County          Snow               14        1999
2588                                     Grant County          Snow               14        1999
2589                                  Hamilton County          Snow               14        1999
2590                                   Hancock County          Snow               14        1999
2591                                 Hendricks County          Snow               14        1999
2592                                     Henry County          Snow               14        1999
2593                                    Howard County          Snow               14        1999
2594                                Huntington County          Snow               14        1999
2595                                    Jasper County          Snow               14        1999
2596                                       Jay County          Snow               14        1999
2597                                   Johnson County          Snow               14        1999
2598                                 Kosciusko County          Snow               14        1999
2599                                  LaGrange County          Snow               14        1999
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier route but I ended up dropping the unused columns from df_Winter -- ei county and disaster type, and then using .groupby and .mean like so:

```
df_winter_length = df_winter.drop(columns=['County','Disaster_Type'])

df_winter_length = df_winter_length.groupby(['Start_year']).mean()
```